# Jitsi Meet server on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

I would like to create a video conferencing system with Jitsi Meet through Ubuntu core 18.04 installed on a Raspberry Pi 4. How should I do it?
P.S. when I control the raspberry remotely and write the sudo apt-get code it tells me that apt is not a valid command. How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Why not install Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Core is snap-only.

- Deb packages (which use apt) are not supported on Core, so the failure of an apt command seems like expected behavior.
- As of June 2020, neither Jitsi nor the Jitsi community have created a Snap for Jitsi Server yet. Sorry.

---

It's possible on Ubuntu Core to create an LXD container that CAN run deb packages. However, it consumes resources and pi machines are not known for their copious resources....

1. Install the LXD snap.
2. Configure LXD
3. Install an Ubuntu-minimal or -server cloud-image into the container.

   - 15GB recommended for a container storage group
4. Login to the container and install the deb using normal apt tools.

Alternately, you can replace Ubuntu Core with Ubuntu Server as the base OS on your pi. [Pi install instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi)

One nice thing about a pi, with it's replaceable SD cards, it that it's fairly easy to try both. If you do try both, be sure to let us know which worked best and why!